# ASP.NET Core Route attributes available in entire controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.2

Is there a way to make attributes specified in the route available in the whole class? For instance, consider this Controller:

```
[Route("api/store/{storeId}/[controller]")]
public class BookController
{
    [HttpGet("{id:int:min(1)}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBookById(int storeId, int id)
    {
    }
}
```

And this request:

```
/api/store/4/book/1
```

Inside the GetBookById method, the storeId variable is correctly populated with 4 and the id variable with 1. However, instead of having to pass the storeId variable in every method of the BookController, is there a way to do something like this:

```
[Route("api/store/{storeId}/[controller]")]
public class BookController
{
    private int storeId;

    [HttpGet("{id:int:min(1)}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBookById(int id)
    {
        //use value of storeId here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the controller inherits from `Controller` class then you can override `OnActionExecuting` method, if the controller inherits from `ControllerBase` you need to implement `IActionFilter` interface to make it work

```
[Route("api/store/{storeId}/[controller]")]
public class BookController : ControllerBase, IActionFilter
{
    private int storeId;

    [HttpGet("{id:int:min(1)}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBookById(int id)
    {
        // use value of storeId here
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        //empty
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        string value = context.RouteData.Values["storeId"].ToString();
        int.TryParse(value, out storeId);
    }
}
```

Or there is a better solution for this using `[FromRoute]` attribute on a controller property (as desribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60078086/7775908))

```
[Route("api/store/{storeId}/[controller]")]
public class BookController : ControllerBase
{
    [FromRoute(Name = "storeId")] 
    public int StoreId { get; set; }

    [HttpGet("{id:int:min(1)}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBookById(int id)
    {
        // use value of storeId here
    }       
}
```