# Controller Query Parameter (not in action)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make a api like the OPENBANKPROJECT. Such as
`/api/banks/{BANK_ID}/atms/{ATM_ID}` etc. I guess `banks` and `atm` is a different controller

I want get a global (`api/Claim/{id}/Detail/[action]` i need this {id}) parameter before before `[action]` initialize (maybe in constructor).

How do i get this `{id}` before `[action]` initialize?

```
    [Route("api/Claim/{id}/Detail/[action]")]
    public class ClaimDetailController
    {
        int _id; // assignment {id} 
        public ClaimDetailController(IClaimDetailService claimDetailService)
        {
           `Need Query Id before execute action`
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<BaseResponse> ClaimDetailInfoPolicy(ClaimDetailKeyModel model)
        {
            return `codes with _id`;
        }
    }

    public class ClaimDetailKeyModel
    {
        public long FileNo { get; set; }
        public long RecourseNo { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248547/get-controller-and-action-name-from-within-controller

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179643/asp-net-core-route-attributes-available-in-entire-controller-class/55181747#55181747)

Comment: @Alexander its a weired solution :) and i am using `[ApiController]` atturibute. Do you have any solution with that atturibute?

Comment: @Alexander that solution is second :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was simple :)

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/Claim/{claimId}/Detail/[action]/")]
public class ClaimDetailController
{
    [FromRoute(Name = "claimId")] 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ClaimDetailController(IClaimDetailService claimDetailService)
    {
      `bla bla`
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<BaseResponse> ClaimDetailInfoPolicy(ClaimDetailKeyModel model)
    {
        return `codes with Id`
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alexander :) just use FromRoute with property :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this id to your request handler.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<BaseResponse> ClaimDetailInfoPolicy(int id, ClaimDetailKeyModel model)
{
    return `codes`;
}
```

Comment: "How do i get this `{id}` before `[action]` initialize?"

Comment: You've done it already `[Route("api/Claim/{id}/Detail/[action]")]`, just put id as mentioned above, it should work.